# Unable to install Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio because of error 0x80070643

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-c++, ssms

I am trying to install SSMS but the error 0x80070643 keeps appearing. It says that I do not have Visual Studio C++ 2017 installed, but the SSMS installer does in fact install Visual Studio C++ 2017. So I don't know why it does not find it.

Here is the part of the installation log where the error seems to appear

```
                      [1130:03E4][2019-10-11T19:15:27]i323: Registering package dependency provider: 
                      {72AFAF21-33FB-45A5-9468-A9EC07427F82}, version: 17.4.1.1, package: 
                       msodbcsql.msi
                       [168C:1B4C][2019-10-11T19:15:27]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageAction: Install 
                       Started for package Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
                       [1130:03E4][2019-10-11T19:15:27]i301: Applying execute package: 
                       msodbcsql.msi, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{72AFAF21- 
                          33FB-45A5-9468-A9EC07427F82}v17.4.1.1\x64\msodbcsql.msi, arguments: ' 
                          MSIFASTINSTALL="7" AddLocal="SQL_SQLODBC_CORE" 
                           IACCEPTMSODBCSQLLICENSETERMS="YES"'
                          [168C:1B4C][2019-10-11T19:15:27]i000: 
                            MainViewModel.OnPackageActionProgress: Percent completed: 0, Overall 
                            progress: 0
                           [168C:1B4C][2019-10-11T19:15:27]e000: 
                              BootstrapperEngineDataModel.OnError: Burn engine encountered error. 
                           PackageId: msodbcsql.msi, ErrorType: WindowsInstaller, ErrorCode: 1723, 
                             Data: 
                         1723,IsPendingRebootKey,IsPendingReboot,C:\WINDOWS\Installer\MSI37D2.tmp, 
                           ErrorMessage: Please install the Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable from 
                            https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vc_redist.x64.exe before running this 
                       installer. , UIHint: 0
```

What can I do to fix it? Already tried to uninstall and install Visual Studio C++ 2017 but it does not work

I installed VS C++ 2017 via the link the error gives me, then restarted the computer, but it still isn't working. Tried to erase it myself and then let the SSMS installer do it for me, but then again, does not work.

I also tried to install the ODBC driver myself, but the same error occurs.

However, with VS C++ 2013 (which is also installed by the SMMS) the error does not occur, as I installed the ODBC 2013 driver and it worked perfectly

[As you can see, VS is installed by the SSMS installer. Curiously, when I download VS c++2017 from the link given by the error it allows me to install it even though it should not because it is already installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCtwJ.png)

Comment: Did you install the ODBC driver for SQL Server? (I don't think the x64 version is installed by default).

Comment: @daShier I tried to install it manually, but the same error occurs. The computer does not recognize Visual Studio C++ 2017 as being installed

Comment: You installed it from the link provided ito vc_redist.x64.exe n the error message? And rebooted your machine at the end of the install as suggested?

Comment: @KenWhite yes, already tried that, but it does not seem to work either

Comment: *does not seem to work* isn't helpful. Either the VS 2017 runtime installer successfully ran or it didn't. Which is it? And did you reboot after doing that installation? (You should be adding details to your post, instead of burying them in comments, and you should make those details specific about what you've done so we don't have to play *20 questions* to get information about what you've tried.)

Comment: @KenWhite Hey, I'm sorry. I am new to the community. Let me specify then in the post then, thank you for helping me.

Comment: @KenWhite okay, I specified it more. Really, thanks for the tips. Any Idea what the error could be?

Comment: Are you running the installer using an administrator account? I've run the SSMS 2016 installer recently (this week, actually, installing it on a new machine) and not had any issues. What does the Windows Event Log say? Any errors or warnings there?

Comment: @KenWhite Yes, I am running it on an admin account. And the Log does not show any more errors apart from the one in the post.

Comment: I didn't ask about the *log*. I asked about the Windows Event Log, which you can access using the *Event Viewer*. It's not the same as the text install log you've posted. Type *Event Viewer* in the Windows search box next to the Start button.

Comment: I know it sounds stupid, but on Windows and thanks to UAC, running something in an administrator account (even *the* Administrator account) is not the same thing as right-clicking on something and choosing `Run as Administrator`. Have you tried right-clicking on the setup program and choosing Run as Administrator? Also, I see you're on a Spanish flavor of Windows - are there Spanish-localized versions of the C++ 2017 Redistributable and SSMS that you need to be installing?

Comment: According to [Error installing Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/93b93cab-f8b9-4982-bcda-ed2765f90963/error-installing-microsoft-odbc-driver-17-for-sql-server) the OP with the same error had Windows Updates pending and fixed his problem by installing the Windows Updates first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the problem was fixed and now I have succesfully installed the ODBC Driver 17.

I had deactivated the antivirus in my computer, downloaded VS C++ 2017 again and then proceeded to install the driver and it finally worked.

This is the only solution that I could find, as other pages did not have a specific answer for it. If you have the same problem, consider doing this and see if the answer is fixed

Thanks to everyone who helped me.

Answer (score 6):

What worked for me is

https://www.accessdbgurus.com/fixing-a-previous-installation-error-with-sql-server-odbc-driver-17-installation/

Plus, I also uninstalled all instances of my Visual C++ Redistributable 2013, as per another suggestion I found.   (I figured I could reinstall this if needed by something.)   I'm unsure if this was related to the fix but I'm including if so.

A reboot was required after the above before it would work.

Comment: Just repairing a couple of these did the trick for me

Comment: I found your 3 steps worked:
1. unistalling the C++ 2013 Redistributable 
2. running the uninstall helper tool against {12DC69AF-787B-4D76-B69D-2716DACA79FB}.
3. doing a full restart before install of SSMS.
finally fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue with latest version.
Uninstalling "Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server" (via Apps & Features) resolves the issue.

SQL Server Management Studio - v18.9.2 - build 15.0.18386.0
SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) - 16.100.46437.65
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools - 15.0.19618.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) - 10.0.19041.1
Microsoft MSXML - 3.0 5.0 6.0
Microsoft .NET Framework - 4.0.30319.42000
Operating System - 10.0.19043

Comment: More of a comment than an answer perhaps - make it better by being specific - what specific version of what for example rather than "latest version" with the next release of whatever that refers to becomes less obvious

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After I review in the log file I figured out the problem with a previous version.

I found two versions of Visual C++ 2013 installed in Program and Features configuation panel. Then I uninstall the older (x64 and x86) and I restarted.

After that, the installation of MSSS (with administrator permitions) worked without problems.

I hope this solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simply uninstall the ODBC driver and try install the SSMS again.
It will install the ODBC driver for you too.